# ファイルを空にするコマンドは？

Tags: linux

`./text.txt`

のファイルを空にしたいです

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`: > ./text.txt`

or

`echo -n > ./text.txt`

これでできます

Answer (score 3):

[truncate](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_coreutils/man1/truncate.1.html)を使う方法

`truncate --size=0 ./text.txt`

Answer (score 2):

cpコマンドを使う例：

`cp /dev/null ./text.txt`

Answer (score 1):

`> ./text.txt`

たぶんこれが一番短いコマンドだと思います（`:` コロンすらいらない）

Comment: これが使えるかはシェルに依存します。csh系だとエラーになりますし、zshだとcat > ./test.txt 相当の動作になります。